# How to set Twitter Bootstrap class=error based on AngularJS input class=ng-invalid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have a problem where my CSS is not taking effect (in Chrome), and I think there is some conflict with Twitter Bootstrap.

```
input.ng-invalid {
    border-color: red;
    outline-color: red;
}
```

My pattern is defined in my controller as:

```
$scope.hexPattern = /^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$/;
```

And copying the HTML from the live DOM, I see that both `ng-invalid` and `ng-invalid-pattern` are set, so my `ng-pattern` must be working.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="salt">Salt: </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="salt" ng-model="salt" ng-pattern="hexPattern" class="ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-pattern">
    </div>
</div>
```

I see that in the "Validation states" section of the [Forms](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) section of Twitter Bootstrap Base CSS, I see I need to add the `error` class to the control-group div.

```
<div class="control-group error">
```

**Question:**  How to set the `class=error` based on the child input `class=ng-invalid`?  Can this be done with some soft of ng-class expression?  Can I set this via code in the controller?  Is there a way to ".$watch" the pattern evaluation like property changes?  Any other ideas to get my "red" outline?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can easily do it with `ng-class` directive:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div class="control-group" ng-class="{ error: myForm.salt.$invalid }">
    <label class="control-label" for="salt">Salt: </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="salt" ng-model="salt" ng-pattern="hexPattern">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RihsxA?p=preview

**EDIT**

Example with bootstrap 3.3.5 and angular 1.4.2:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.salt.$invalid }">
    <label class="control-label" for="salt">Salt: </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="salt" ng-model="salt" ng-pattern="hexPattern">
  </div>
</form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5JNCrY8yQmcnA9ysC7Vc?p=preview

Comment: This worked for me once I added `name="salt"` instead of just `id="salt"`

Comment: For me too, I had to add the `name=""` attribute for this to work.

Comment: This didn't work for me and I'm not sure why.  Has this changed some how with the newest version of AngularJS?

Comment: Figured it out. Bootstrap's class name is "has-error".  The dash caused a javascript error so I had to wrap it in single quotes.

Comment: Note: In the attribute `ng-class="{ error: myForm.salt.$invalid }"`, the `salt` term is a reference to the `input` with `name="salt"`, not the `ng-model`.

Comment: This was great, but like what @Drellgor said, you need the has error. like so    ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.salt.$invalid}"

Comment: @ConnorLeech added example for boostrap 3.3.5

Answer (score 9):

I think a better solution is to just add your own CSS rules. It makes the code much simpler and, as a bonus, you can set the rule to only apply to "dirty" elements. That way fields will only be highlighted after the user has tried to enter something.

In my application I've just added this css, based on an example in [the AngularJS forms documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

```
/* Forms */
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: red;
  outline-color: red;
}
.ng-valid.ng-dirty {
  border-color: green;
  outline-color: green;
}
```