# How do I access the child ngModel from a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859011/how-to-set-twitter-bootstrap-class-error-based-on-angularjs-input-class-ng-inval), I want to add `.error` on a form field's parent `.control-group` when `scope.$invalid` is true.

However, hardcoding the form name like in `ng-class="{ error: formName.fieldModel.$invalid }"` means that I can't reuse this in different forms, plus I'd rather not repeat this declaration everywhere.

I figured that a directive that looks something like this could work:

```
<div class="control-group" error-on="model1, model2">
  <input ng-model="model1">
  <input ng-model="model2">
</div>
```

So when either `model1` or `model2` is not valid, `.control-group` gets `.error` added.

[My attempt here](http://jsfiddle.net/thatmarvin/pFV4n/3/). Is it possible to access the models from the directive, given the model names?

If there's a better approach, I'd love to hear it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that writing a custom directive is necessery for this use-case as the [`ng-form` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angForm) was created exactly for situations like those. From the directive's documentation:

> It is useful to nest forms, for example if the validity of a sub-group
>   of controls needs to be determined.

Taking your code as an example one would write:

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{ error: myControlGroup1.$invalid }>
  <ng-form name="myControlGroup1">
    <input ng-model="model1">
    <input ng-model="model2">
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

By using this technique you don't need to repeat expressions used in ng-model and can reuse this fragment inside any form.

Comment: Awesome, this looks like the cleanest and most angular-y way of doing things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the markup in the accepted answer to do without the nesting, since `ng-form` is also a class directive:

```
<div class="control-group ng-form" name="controlGroup11" ng-class="{ error: controlGroup1.$invalid }>
  <input ng-model="model1">
  <input ng-model="model2">
</div>
```

[Final solution Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thatmarvin/55bJS/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your link function, you can get access to the [formController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController).  It has all of the controls.  So the following will give your directive access to `.$valid`:

```
el.controller('form')[attrs.errorOn].$valid
```

However, I don't know how to watch that for changes.  I tried watching `attrs.errorOn` (i.e., watch the ng-model property), but the watch doesn't trigger unless a valid value is input (because of the way Angular forms work... unless that value is valid, it is not assigned to the scope property set by ng-model.)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/4PAQr/).

Maybe someone can take this further...