# Setting Bootstrap Error Class via AngularJS on Form Submit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I efficiently set the error state of multiple form field **after** the user submits the form?

I can set the error state easily enough on a constant basis.  As described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859011/how-to-set-twitter-bootstrap-class-error-based-on-angularjs-input-class-ng-inval) I use the following HTML code:

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{ error: groupForm.textbox_Group.$invalid }">
  <label class="control-label" for="textbox_Group"><i class="icon-home"></i> Organization</label>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <input type="text" class="span6" id="textbox_Group" name="textbox_Group" placeholder="Organization" ng-model="org" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue with this is that it will appear in the error state immediately on the page loading.  I want it to appear normal before the user hits submit and then, only if it is `$invalid` to be flagged.

I'm currently using individual flags, along the lines of:

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{ error: group.isInvalid }">
  <!-- snip -->
</div>

<div class="control-group" ng-class="{ error: date.isInvalid }">
  <!-- snip -->
</div>
```

It works, but seems very bloated to me.  Is there a more streamlined way to flag any form fields in an `$invalid` state, but only after that form is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scope variable that defaults to false that tracks when the button is clicked.

```
$scope.formSubmitted = false
```

The on your form add a ng-submit directive to change the condition to true.

```
<form name='myForm' ng-submit="formSubmitted=true" >
```

Now change the ng class condition:

```
ng-class="{ error: date.isInvalid && formSubmitted }"
```