# Check which field is not valid in form with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to check which fields aren't valid after 5 seconds when form is rendered. I have a button and I set this `ng-disabled="!step1Form.$valid"` but I need to add some kind of CSS class maybe red to fields which are not valid, can any give me some help?

This is the field where I want to set the invalid pattern:

```
<div ng-form="logoForm" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;" class="info-picture main ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
    <div add-pic="" class="small-button">Agregar logo</div>
    <input type="file" required="required" ng-model="logo.company" id="company_logo" style="display:none;" ng-file-select="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `ng-invalid` css class, its added to invalid form object you can use it

Comment: @Satpal I edited the main post take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add css Class to any component you can use the "ng-class" directive.

You can see this in documentation at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Another question like yours is this: [How to set Twitter Bootstrap class=error based on AngularJS input class=ng-invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859011/how-to-set-twitter-bootstrap-class-error-based-on-angularjs-input-class-ng-inval)